# Diagnosing 98 Camry red dashboard indicator: "brake"

Tags: toyota, brakes, camry

98 Camry: A red "brake" indicator is lit underneath the speedometer.  The emergency brake was engaged / disengaged several time to ensure that it is not the cause.

I filled up power steering reservoir and verified two white lights above license plate are functioning. Reverse lights work as expected.

What is the next diagnostic step?

Comment: Have you checked the level of brake fluid in the master? Also ensure the wiring to the level indicator in the master to ensure it is doing its thing. I think you can test it by pulling the plug then jumping the wires in the plug. If the light goes out when you do it, it could be the sensor in the side of the reservoir.

Comment: You also need to check the actual parking brake switch. It's a physical switch located at the off position of the parking brake handle or peddle. If you confirm this switch and the sensor that @Paulster2 mentioned are both good you may be experiencing a dangerous brake problem.

Comment: @jupiter What exactly is the nature of the dangerous brake problem?

Comment: A red brake light on the dash is interpreted as very potential brake failure. It will also come on when the parking brake is applied. It comes on when the fluid level is low. So if these two issues are resolved by making sure the parking brake switch is functioning and the fluid level sensor is working and the fluid level is good, you must have another issue at hand. This is when you should take the red warning light at face value and assume that you can be operating with potential brake failure until it is diagnosed.